# Create tabs inside tab panel dynamically based on a given value

Tags: extjs, extjs5

Hi I have just started learning Sencha .

I need to create a tab panel in view and dynamically add tab panels to it ...

Number of tab panels can be changed

If the number is set to 2, we need to create 2 tab panels and if its set to 4 we need to create 4 tab panels

can anyone guide me please ?

Comment: You only want to make 1 tab panel. You will then add panels to it.  What code have you tried thus far? 'tabpanel.add()' should be your ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [example fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/qa4) that adds new tabs to tab panel dynamically.

Code:

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.Tab', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.mytab',
    html: 'Tab content'
});


Ext.application({
    name : 'myapp',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
            reference: 'tabpanel',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: {
                xtype: 'mytab'
                ,title: 'First tab'
            },
            tbar: [{
                xtype: 'numberfield',
                value: 3
            },{
                text: 'Add tabs'
                ,handler: function(btn) {
                    var tabPanel = btn.up('tabpanel'),
                        numTabs = tabPanel.down('numberfield').getValue(),
                        i;
                    for (i = 1; i <= numTabs; i++) {
                        tabPanel.add({
                            xtype: 'mytab',
                            title: 'Tab #'+i,
                            html: 'Content for tab '+i
                        });
                    }                    
                }
            }]
        });        
    }
});
```